# What’s the correct hyphenation in “trying to be a decision maker”?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

Which of these three ways of writing it is right:

1. *decision maker* (a space separates the two pieces)
2. *decision-maker* (a hyphen separates the two pieces)
3. *decisionmaker* (nothing separates the two pieces)

I’ve looked online and in dictionaries, grammar books, source documents, and multiple documents within my organization, but I still cannot find an answer.

Comment: It's [usually *not* hyphenated](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decision-maker%2Cdecision+maker%2Cdecisionmaker&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecision%20-%20maker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecision%20maker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecisionmaker%3B%2Cc0), as that NGram shows. But you can include a hyphen (or just go for the single-word form) if you want. Unless you're constrained by some particular style guide, the choice is yours. So it's Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: What did you find?

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is my gut feeling as well, but I am just  not willing to trust hyphenation ngrams until I can actually search their results, which is not presently possible. They do not provide links as they do for everything else, so it is not verifiable.

Comment: The Ngram chart that FumbleFingers links to doesn't match "decision maker" (and "decisionmaker") against "decision-maker" but against "decision - maker" ("decision [minus] maker," whatever that is). If you look at the matches for "decision maker," you'll see that those results include instances of "decision-maker" treated as though the hyphen were a letter space—which is precisely how Ngram deals with hyphenated words. Currently, Ngram is utterly misleading in any representation of frequencies of use that involve hyphenated words.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use whatever style guide is appropriate for your organization or audience.
2. If there is no appropriate style guide, then here is a general guideline (and it is **only** a general guideline):

   - Use a hyphen if the term is used as an adjective: *XYZ is a decision-maker tool*.
   - Do not use a hyphen if the term is used as a noun phrase: *She is a decision maker.*
3. Beyond that, @FumbleFingers's comment applies: it's pretty much up to you.

Comment: Any dictionary will have quite a lot of headwords that end in *maker*, and new ones are being coined all the time like *filmmaker*. Common words include *kingmaker*, *lawmaker*, *shoemaker*, and  *peacemaker* without any separation, compared with words like *mischief-maker* and *boiler-maker* with hyphen.  The words with a space om them tend to be longer ones, like *chair frame maker* and *sandwich maker*, but *drug maker* is short.  Of course, these are all the same word no matter which of the three ways of spelling them is chosen.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes this is true. 1. Check a dictionary first. 2. There is often an evolution from separate words to hyphenated and then to contiguous (one word, no hyphen). And sometimes the hyphenated step is skipped.

Answer (score -1):

I have been a licensed court reporter for 27 years.  In my career, I *have to* know how to accurately spell words and use the proper grammar and punctuation.  A vital resource tool for this has been the reference book called "One Word, Two Words, Hyphenated?" book written by Mary Louise Gilman, published in 1998 by the National Court Reporters Association.  It is a *priceless* resource I have used constantly since 1998.

In this book, it shows to use a hyphen for this word, so it would be:

> decision-maker

Comment: For the noun or the adjective??  There's a significant difference.